# Python Programming Exersize

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am stuck on this problem, it is in Python:

**Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number.**

This is the code that I have right now:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
     num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
     if num == "done" : break

     try:
          num = float(num)
     except:
          print "Invalid input"
          continue 

     if num > largest:
         largest = num
     elif num < smallest:
         smallest = num

     largest = str(largest)
     smallest = str(smallest)    


print "Maximum " + "is " + largest
print "Minimum " + "is " + smallest
```

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: looks good to me. I don't get it though, is this a question?

Comment: You did not ask a question or state a problem with your code.  Read the help pages.

Answer (score 1):

You had a few indent issues, and the logic wasn't working. If you input numbers in different order, it would output the wrong results. I included comments in the code for you to check out.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    # Move try here, as it would previously crash if you left a blank line
    try:
        num = raw_input("Enter a number: \n")
    except:
        # Field was left blank
        print "Invalid input"
        continue

    if num == "done":
        break
    else:
        if num.lstrip('-').replace('.', '').isdigit(): # No need for a try here, check if it's a valid number (replace and lstrip to include floats and negatives)
            num = float(num)
            # Auto-set if it's None
            if largest is None or num > largest:
                largest = num
            if smallest is None or num < smallest:
                smallest = num
        else:
            # Field was not a number
            print "Invalid input"

# Print results
print "Maximum is {0}".format(largest)
print "Minimum is {0}".format(smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dedent these two lines

```
 largest = str(largest)
 smallest = str(smallest)
```

so they are not executed until the loop has exited.

Or just leave them out and let `print` do the conversion

```
print "Maximum is ", largest
print "Minimum is ", smallest
```

You should also prime those values in the loop if they are `None`

```
    if num is None or num > largest:
         largest = num
    if smallest is None or num < smallest:
         smallest = num
```